# Modify a tomboy note via AWK - Extract text from one file and add it inside an existing .note file

Tags: awk

TL/DR
**When I run this**:

```
awk 'NR>113 && NR<124 { print }' Ninpomovements.txt > buffer.txt;
Filenames="$(awk -F '|' '$1 == "Ichi no Kamae" { gsub("=",""); print $2;exit; }' notesurllist.txt)";
awk 'NR==FNR{bfile = bfile $0 RS; next} /Describe your new note here/{printf "%s", bfile} {print}' buffer.txt "$Filenames" >temp.txt && temp.txt "$Filenames"
```

**I GET THIS**

```
temp.txt: Command not found:
```

**What I want to achieve**:

Extract lines 113-124 from file ninpomovements.txt and add them inside a tomboy note (to be discovered).

**1 - Get lines between 113 and 124:**

```
awk 'NR>113 && NR<124 { print }' Ninpomovements.txt > buffer.txt (I would skip the buffer.txt if I know how)
```

**2 - Find the note file name:**

```
Filenames="$(awk -F '|' '$1 == "Ichi no Kamae" { gsub("=",""); print $2;exit; }' notesurllist.txt)"
```

**3 - Replace the description text for lines 113-124:**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{bfile = bfile $0 RS; next} /Describe your new note here/{printf "%s", bfile} {print}' buffer.txt "$Filenames" >temp.txt
```

(I would skip the temp.txt file if I knew how to edit the file without ending with an empty one)

**This prints what I want:**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{bfile = bfile $0 RS; next} /Describe your new note here/{printf "%s", bfile} {print}' buffer.txt b77312ce-09ca-4271-8e7a-2b1bcc53e7fd.note
```

**This prints what I want:**
    Filenames=b77312ce-09ca-4271-8e7a-2b1bcc53e7fd.note; awk 'NR==FNR{bfile = bfile $0 RS; next} /Describe your new note here/{printf "%s", bfile} {print}' buffer.txt b77312ce-09ca-4271-8e7a-2b1bcc53e7fd.note;
    awk 'NR==FNR{bfile = bfile $0 RS; next} /Describe your new note here/{printf "%s", bfile} {print}' buffer.txt "$Filenames"

4 Save previous output to the file stored in $Filenames (b77312ce-09ca-4271-8e7a-2b1bcc53e7fd.note)

**------NINPOMOVEMENTS.TXT-----**

Ichi no Kamae (Hira no Kamae) (No. One Posture – Flat Posture) = 一之構(平之構)

From Shizen no Kamae step back with the right foot. The feet are approximately 2 1⁄2 to 3 feet apart with about a 1 inch gap between. The front foot (left) is angled very slightly to the right. This is not noticeable to the Uke. The back foot (right) points 45 degrees to the rear. Lower your centre of gravity as much as is comfortable (this takes time). Your knees should hide your feet if you are looking down (important point). Make sure the knees are not buckling inwards to take the strain. This will hurt initially but the pain is temporary and, if practiced correctly, will build strong legs. This is an important point. Your back needs to be angled along the line of this Kamae – you do this by leaning your body slightly back, then with a feeling of rotating your lower torso clockwise to the point when the hips lock This will ensure that the back is straight. Make sure your backside is not sticking out. This is a common mistake and should be corrected from the start. Keep your shoulders relaxed and do not hunch them. Your left arm is pointed to the Uke’s chest with a slight bend at the elbow so the arm is not locked (the Kanji for Ichi is a horizontal line, so your lead hand should emulate this). The hand is held in such a way that your palm is obscured from the Uke’s vision. The fingers are held straight and together (no tension). Do not open them. The left hand should be roughly perpendicular to the left foot. The right hand is held about a fist width away from the chin – again your palm is hidden. Both hands resemble a loose Shuto fist.

Remember, keep the shoulders relaxed. Your head and neck should follow the line of your spine with the head facing forwards. Do not tilt your head to the side. This is a common mistake and should be corrected from the start. Fix your eyes on the Uke. Take all tension out of your body and relax. This is Hidari (left) Ichi no Kamae. Do this on the other side also (Migi (right) Ichi no Kamae).

Kuden The feeling for this Kamae is not allowing the Uke to get close to you

**----------end--------**

**---TOMBOY NOTE BEFORE-----**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<note version="0.3" xmlns:link="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/link" xmlns:size="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/size" xmlns="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy">
  <title>Ichi no Kamae</title>
  <text xml:space="preserve"><note-content version="0.1">Ichi no Kamae

Describe your new note here.</note-content></text>
  <last-change-date>2019-12-28T14:50:59.9032170-03:00</last-change-date>
  <last-metadata-change-date>2019-12-28T14:50:59.9040250-03:00</last-metadata-change-date>
  <create-date>2019-12-28T14:50:59.5485530-03:00</create-date>
  <cursor-position>0</cursor-position>
  <selection-bound-position>-1</selection-bound-position>
  <width>0</width>
  <height>0</height>
  <x>-1</x>
  <y>-1</y>
  <open-on-startup>False</open-on-startup>
</note>
```

-----------end--------

**------TOMBOY NOTE AFTER-----**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<note version="0.3" xmlns:link="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/link" xmlns:size="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy/size" xmlns="http://beatniksoftware.com/tomboy">
  <title>Ichi no Kamae</title>
  <text xml:space="preserve"><note-content version="0.1">Ichi no Kamae



From Shizen no Kamae step back with the right foot. The feet are approximately 2 1⁄2 to 3 feet apart with about a 1 inch gap between. The front foot (left) is angled very slightly to the right. This is not noticeable to the Uke. The back foot (right) points 45 degrees to the rear. Lower your centre of gravity as much as is comfortable (this takes time). Your knees should hide your feet if you are looking down (important point). Make sure the knees are not buckling inwards to take the strain. This will hurt initially but the pain is temporary and, if practiced correctly, will build strong legs. This is an important point. Your back needs to be angled along the line of this Kamae – you do this by leaning your body slightly back, then with a feeling of rotating your lower torso clockwise to the point when the hips lock This will ensure that the back is straight. Make sure your backside is not sticking out. This is a common mistake and should be corrected from the start. Keep your shoulders relaxed and do not hunch them. Your left arm is pointed to the Uke’s chest with a slight bend at the elbow so the arm is not locked (the Kanji for Ichi is a horizontal line, so your lead hand should emulate this). The hand is held in such a way that your palm is obscured from the Uke’s vision. The fingers are held straight and together (no tension). Do not open them. The left hand should be roughly perpendicular to the left foot. The right hand is held about a fist width away from the chin – again your palm is hidden. Both hands resemble a loose Shuto fist.


Remember, keep the shoulders relaxed. Your head and neck should follow the line of your spine with the head facing forwards. Do not tilt your head to the side. This is a common mistake and should be corrected from the start. Fix your eyes on the Uke. Take all tension out of your body and relax. This is Hidari (left) Ichi no Kamae. Do this on the other side also (Migi (right) Ichi no Kamae).

Kuden The feeling for this Kamae is not allowing the Uke to get close to you

Describe your new note here.</note-content></text>
  <last-change-date>2019-12-28T14:50:59.9032170-03:00</last-change-date>
  <last-metadata-change-date>2019-12-28T14:50:59.9040250-03:00</last-metadata-change-date>
  <create-date>2019-12-28T14:50:59.5485530-03:00</create-date>
  <cursor-position>0</cursor-position>
  <selection-bound-position>-1</selection-bound-position>
  <width>0</width>
  <height>0</height>
  <x>-1</x>
  <y>-1</y>
  <open-on-startup>False</open-on-startup>
</note>
```

Code that finally worked

```
awk 'NR>113 && NR<124 { print }' Ninpomovements.txt > buffer.txt;Filenames="$(awk -F '|' '$1 == "Ichi no Kamae" { gsub("=",""); print $2;exit; }' notesurllist.txt)";awk 'NR==FNR{bfile = bfile $0 RS; next} /Describe your new note here/{printf "%s", bfile} {print}' buffer.txt "$Filenames" > temp.txt; mv temp.txt "$Filenames"
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `awk '..script..' inFile > outFile | awk .. more stuff` ? At a minimum, you need to replace the `|` with a `;`, but please, please reformat that last line so we can read it without having to scroll right! Good luck.

Comment: It will also help improve your chances of getting meaningful help if you include the smallest amount of sample data and expected output at each stage of your processing. If you're getting incorrect output or error messages, be sure to include them. Good luck.

Comment: AND based on your title, "failing to change the file", it's not clear if you expect a `sed`-like feature `-i` (inplace), (which is available in some versions of `awk` as `--inplace`) OR if you understand that you must do something like `awk '{program}' inFile > tmpFile && /bin/mv tmpFile inFile` to get the changes in you `inFile`. Rather than reply in comments, please update your Q so I can remove these comments so that other readers won't have to slog thru them ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: I answered / changed the question the best I could.  I just want to grab the right lines from ninpomovements.txt, find the note file, then add the copied lines at the right place. Then save the note file with the changes. Thanks! @shellter

Comment: Note I said the ***smallest*** amount of **sample** data. Can  you please reduce your sample data to a small set of *words" that must be matched by a small sentence (not 3 paragraphs) and a small XML document. AND use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format correctly as `code/data/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: In two places under `#3` above you say, "this prints what I want". So does `awk '{program}' file1 file2 > newFile` product a good file? If so AND you are comfortable overwriting your basic data file, then you can do `/bin/mv newFile file1` (or is it `file2`?). ? Good luck.

Comment: Arg. I wish I had noticed this sooner : **" would skip the temp.txt file"**. As I mentioned you'll need an `awk` that supports the `--inplace` feature (and you may need to install something to use it). BUT really, in 99.99% cases of real-world inplace editing, the editing program is relying on a `temp.txt` sort of file. Once you "close" the file, the newFile is `mv`ed to the Original file. Don't waste more time on this issue! There is no benefit to it in shell scripting. Good luck.

Comment: Hi @shellter thanks very much. I have 2000 more lines to match. This was my best post ever in stackoverflow, so your patience was highly appreciated. You didn't notice the comment before because I added it after the fact. I got it working now. I did this: awk 'NR>113 && NR<124 { print }' Ninpomovements.txt > buffer.txt;Filenames="$(awk -F '|' '$1 == "Ichi no Kamae" { gsub("=",""); print $2;exit; }' notesurllist.txt)";awk 'NR==FNR{bfile = bfile $0 RS; next} /Describe your new note here/{printf "%s", bfile} {print}' buffer.txt "$Filenames" > temp.txt; mv temp.txt "$Filenames"

Comment: @SantigoMarcosDemierre : Glad you got a solution! Keep posting, and use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu to give you new Qs good formatting. Don't forget to include small copy/pasteable sets of input data, expected output, error messages (exact, not just "it isn't working") and your code for your best attempt to solve to your problem (as you have done above). Send me a message with @shellter as a comment on your new Qs if you need help. Good luck!

Comment: And finally, you wrote "I have 2000 more lines to match". OK, that could get tricky. Don't post a Q with a link to your 2000 lines, but do include a sample file with 2 lines. If you get it to work for 2 lines, then 2000 should work (but take 1000x times ;-/!) . .....

Comment: AND I am worried about your resulting data file. It's very easy to corrupt an XML file, so I would advice using a layered approach to your file names, so you never destroy your original data, until your project has been running for a year. So `awk '{prog}' file1 file2 > newFile` and just use `newFile` in the rest of your script. If you need to make `newFile2`, `..., newFileN` in each step of the process, you will be safeter.  Now `file1` and `file2` have not be harmed by any changes you make and if you discover a reason to rewrite program, you still have your original data. Got to go.GoodLuck!